# How to correlate/use regular expression for empty or new line right boundary in JMeter

Tags: regex, jmeter, correlation

Example:
In a response headers I see,
state=a5d73a14-a728-4f0f-afae-de5fda55d002
Here I can use LB as state= and there is no right boundary.
So I tried using regular expression extractor as:

state=(.+)

and replaced the hard coded value in the next request as ${state}

The requests are failing as it takes ${state} itself in the request URL, it means regular expression extractor is not working. I know I have placed the function rightly. Still I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestion would really help!

Comment: Try without right boundary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should search the response in main and sub samples. Before I was searching for response only in main sample's so it failed.
same regular expression worked: when there is no right boundary or new line right boundary.
state=(.+)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXmSQ.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score -1):

Actually your regex should work, maybe it fails due to line break or something, to be on the safe side try using `state=(.*)` as the regular expression, it should be less restrictive:

[image]

Also the value of your "state" looks like a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) so you can try looking up a guid-like structure instead:

```
state=([A-Fa-f0-9]{8}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-][A-Fa-f0-9]{4}[\-]([A-Fa-f0-9]){12})
```

[image]

And last but not the least, by default Regular Expression Extractor looks into **response body** so you need to change the "Field to check" to **Response Headers**

[image]

More information:

- [JMeter Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Perl 5 Regex Cheat sheet](https://perlmaven.com/regex-cheat-sheet)
- [Using Regular Expressions to Extract Tokens and Session IDs to Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-to-extract-tokens-and-session-ids-to-variables)